# Add class on AJAX success and remove it on complete

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've an Ajax call and as it sends data to my server, and then my server makes a connection to a third provider, I'd like to add some kind of loader so the user doesn't feel the page just freezed.

```html
<div class="general-container"></div>
```

```js
if (Culqi.token) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "{% url 'cart:cart_charge' %}",
    data: {
      amount: {{ culqi_total }},
      currency_code: 'PEN',
      email: Culqi.token.email,
      source_id: Culqi.token.id,
      last_four: Culqi.token.last_four,
    },
    success: function() {
      $('.general-container').addClass("preloader");
    },
    complete: function() {
      $('.general-container').addClass("complete");
    }
  })
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.preloader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*background: #000;*/
  transition: 1s;
}

.preloader:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  transition: 1s;
}

.preloader:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  transition: 1s;
}

.preloader.complete:before {
  left: -50%;
}

.preloader.complete:after {
  right: -50%;
}
```

Plus, apart from removing the "preloader" black background, I'd like to redirect user to this URL (I'm using Django):

```
window.location.href = "{% url 'cart:thank_you' %}";
```

Comment: You just need to change `addClass()` to `removeClass()` in `complete`. *However* those two calls will be made within milliseconds of each other, so they are largely redundant. Also, the UI won't appear to freeze at all as the request is async, so I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: So after user makes a payment, it takes abount 5 seconds to redirect to the thank you page. I did redirect user with `done` method, but as I don't know how to `addClass` and also redirect on `success`, I've put this `redirect` as the plus part in my question.

Comment: If you're redirecting the page why do you need to add a class in the `success` anyway? It would only be visible for less than a second - if at all. Are you instead intending to add the class when the AJAX request *starts*?

Comment: Yes, when it start, until it complets. And when done, redirect user to the thank-you page.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. I added an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments you stated that your intention is to add the class to `.general-container` when the AJAX request *starts*. This is different to your current logic as you are adding the class when the AJAX request completes successfully.

To do what you require, add the class *before* you call `$.ajax()`, then you can remove it (if needed) in `success` before you perform the redirect. Something like this:

```
if (Culqi.token) {
  var $container = $('.general-container').addClass("preloader");
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "{% url 'cart:cart_charge' %}",
    data: {
      amount: {{ culqi_total }},
      currency_code: 'PEN',
      email: Culqi.token.email,
      source_id: Culqi.token.id,
      last_four: Culqi.token.last_four,
    },
    success: function() {
      $container.addClass("complete");
      window.location.href = "{% url 'cart:thank_you' %}";
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('something went wrong, do some debugging!');
    }
  })
}
```

Note that the `complete` class *may* not be visible when you do the redirect as the page may be unloaded as you've changed the page location.